# Сумма определенных элементов двумерного массива

Tags: python, list

Необходимо Создать двумерный целочисленный массив и найдите сумму всех его элементов, имеющих оба нечетных индекса

```
def func(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
            if i % 2 != 0:
                for j in range(len(array[i])):
                        if j % 2 !=0:
                            print(array[i][j]) # делаю проверку, что получается.
        
    a =[[9, 5, 3, 9, 3], [6, 10, 8, 9, 4]]
    print(func(a))
```

Элементы с нечетными индексами нашла, но не могу понять как их сложить. Конечно, может быть и в целом код не верный.

Comment: Создать переменную, инициализировать её 0, складывать в нее `array[i][j]`??? Уже второй такой вопрос, где автор знает как реализовать цикл, но не знает как создать переменную. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257773/Как-умножить-полученные-цифры-друг-на-друга#comment2210355_1257773) первый, можете почитать комментарии под вопросом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так как 0 - является чётным числом то организуем циклы начиная с единицы с шагом 2 :

```
def func(array):
    result_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, len(array), 2):
        for j in range(1, len(array[i]), 2):
            result_sum += array[i][j]
    return result_sum
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, только никогда не называйте переменные именами зарезервированных слов питона. `sum` - это встроенная функция питона, вы её перекрываете своей переменной.

Comment: взято из вопроса. не стал исправлять :)

Comment: Не вижу такой переменной в коде вопроса %)

Comment: оу... упустил :) спасибо. Ну переопределил бы sum да и всё, чего уж тут :)